# Submit button with different functions

Tags: javascript, html

I have `radio button` input, `text field` input and `password field` input and one `submit button`.
What I want to happen is, if I click the `submit` button without choosing or entering those three form, window alert will show saying "You need to fill up the (radio button, text field and password field)" something like that. How can I do that?

This is my code

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="optradio">Menu 1
  <input type="radio" name="optradio">Menu 2 <br>
  <input type="text"><br>
  <input type="password"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="alert('Hello! I am an alert box!')">
</form>
```

Comment: you need to write JavaScript function to validate input fields

Comment: Where's your attempt at the JavaScript code?

Comment: better remove the question try yourself first , research yourself then post it again with your attempt. Else unnecessarily it will be down-voted and removed.

Comment: Use jQuery Validations.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the using [**`required`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) attribute

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" required>Menu 1
  <input type="radio" name="optradio">Menu 2 <br>
  <input type="text" required><br>
  <input type="password" required><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own function and you can check whether value exist or not.
Example:

```
function myFun(){
    if(val1&&val2&&val3){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate this using Javascript

```js
function validation(){
  radio_1_value = document.getElementById("radio_1").value;
  radio_2_value = document.getElementById("radio_2").value;
  text_value = document.getElementById("text").value;
  password_value = document.getElementById("password").value;
  if (radio_1_value == '' || radio_2_value == '' || text_value == '' || password_value == ''){
    alert('You need to fill up the (radio button, text field and password field');
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="radio_1" name="optradio" required>Menu 1
  <input type="radio" id="radio_2" name="optradio">Menu 2 <br>
  <input type="text" id="text" required><br>
  <input type="password" id="password" required><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validation()">
</form>
```